# Migrating rails mongoid to activerecord, db:migrate running activerecord second time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm converting a Rails application that's based on mongo to postgres.  I want to run both DBs concurrently in order to migrate objects.  I created the model and migration and then run rake db:migrate (after setting up the postgres db) and I see the model table successfully created.  I then see what appears to be a mongo migration running and for some reason this is invoking the activerecord migrations in db/migrate a second time and causing an error since the table was already created.

Is there any way to have db:migrate NOT run on the activerecord migrations when it's running the mongoid migrations?  I commented the following line out of the migrate task in the mongoid gem but this is not an ideal solution.

Mongoid::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate/", ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil)

from the rakefile:
gems/mongoid_rails_migrations-1.0.1/lib/mongoid_rails_migrations/mongoid_ext/railties/database.rake

Thanks in advance.